# Access "server-side" model methods on TastyPie Resource

Tags: django, django-models, tastypie

I got this Resource and It's working fine and listing all the attributes from Employee's.

```
class EmployeeResource(ModelResource):
    journey = fields.ForeignKey(WorkJourney, 'work_journey')
    class Meta:
        queryset = Employee.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'employee'
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

I have a method writen on Employee's model Class that lists the phone number's from an Employee (Terrible code imo., i think it should be an attribute but i can't change it).

```
@property
def phones(self):
    return u' / '.join([self.personal_phones or u'', self.institutional_phones or u''])
```

The point is to write a Resource method that access that Model method and list results with Employee's attributes..

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create it as a read-only field in your resource:

```
phones = fields.CharField(attribute='phones', readonly=True)
```

If you don't set `readonly=True`, Tastypie will try and set the field's value on insert/update.

Answer (score 1):

If your Phone model look like this:

```
class Phone(models.Model)
     employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name=phones)
```

Then you can get list of all phones for the employee with defining in your EmployeeResource ToManyRelation with phones:

```
class EmployeeResource(ModelResource):
   phones = fields.ToManyField(PhoneResource, 'phones', full=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    resource_name = 'employee'
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
```

Also with override dehydrate method you can customize data what will be send to the client side.

Custom view is another solution for sending customize data.